# How to fix Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found. in android studio

Tags: maven, android-studio

I am creating an android application in android studio. I am adding a library to my project which was downloaded from [here](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) . When i was adding this library to my project it was showing an error called **"Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found."**. Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 49):

In top level build.gradle dependencies, paste this classpaths.
I wonder why cant i've seen this method in websites.
Anyway, I fixed it using this way.

```
dependencies {
    //YOUR DEPEDENCIES
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score 26):

There come two scenarios here:

1. If you are using `apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'` in your module level gradle.

This plugin is generally used to distribute and upload your library project to **bintaray**.

In this case, all you have to do is make use of correct combinations of **gradle plugin** and **maven-gradle-plugin**.

The combination of the following versions is working for me:

Inside **project level gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0+'
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
```

and in **gradle-wrapper.properties**

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

In module level gradle:`apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'`

You can check the compatible versions list from [Github](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin#note-on-releases)

2. If you are not using it, as it is in your case just remove

   ```
   classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
   classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
   ```

and

```
apply plugin: com.github.dcendents.android-maven
```

Comment: The link to the version list was invaluable. In the Android Studio gradle sync you get no warning of an incompatibilty - just various ghastly failures!

Comment: Android Gradle plugin 3.6.0 and higher include support for the Maven Publish Gradle plugin, which allows you to publish build artifacts to an Apache Maven repository. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin

Comment: Bintray is now down: https://isdown.app/integrations/bintray#:~:text=The%20official%20status%20page%20is,service%20has%20now%20been%20sunset.

Answer (score 11):

Just delete the line "apply plugin: 'android-maven'" 
in the beginning of build.gradle,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

the project doesn't need maven.

Comment: this is the perfect answer for the question. to the point and brief. this should be marked as accepted answer

Comment: it generates this error ERROR: Plugin with id 'android-maven' not found

Answer (score 11):

For a Gradle 7, I deleted this line in the build.gradle module level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

Comment: Thank you for making this possible for me.

Answer (score 10):

Try to add these lines to your project's build.gradle file into dependencies block:

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
```

Like this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
}
```

It just worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

For a Gradle 4.1+ you could do in Project-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.7.3"
    id "com.github.dcendents.android-maven" version "2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add these lines in project.gradle dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add this two line in your gradle file

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

With reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769596/974766) posted above, I encountered another problem [No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825451/no-service-of-type-factory-available-in-projectscopeservices) after using it.

I fixed it by including `com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1` ( as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38871519/974766) to the above linked question) instead of `com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2` in the dependencies in the project gradle.

Don't be too confused. `android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1` is only an updated version of the `android-maven-plugin:1.2` . As mentioned in the `Readme` in the [git repo for this plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-plugin), `dcendents` mentioned that he was requested to rename the plugin name by Android maven plugin developers.

Answer (score 2):

This is all depend your gradle version. please check https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin i found my solution in there.

```
 dependencies {
    // The gradle plugin and the maven plugin have to be updated after each version of Android
    // studio comes out
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**finally** i can solve this error after trying three days

the solution is very simple just remove the module or library project completely from your project and use gradle dependency instead.

Just copy this in your app module's build.gradle inside dependencies closure

```
dependencies {
 // YOUR OTHER DEPENDENCIES
 compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'}
```

to success make this steps when you r online

Comment: but i guess it work as admob adds but not show in xml design board but it will appear when you try to run project

Comment: it work but in run time because design generated when code run

Answer (score 1):

If in your project any module using this id then you must declare below two dependency at your project level build.gradle file -

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
```

Comment: upvoted for simple reason behind this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that android just, don't know the repos and you must specify the repository like that:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

Answer (score 1):

add following under project level gradle file

```
dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'

    }
```

Comment: This plugin required for Jitpack Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Github library version as your Gradle version and Github library version doesn't match.

Check the version compatibility here:
https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It probably causes from android sdk . So i don't know how to occur it but i solved it following these steps.

1. If you see these warnings on the begining of the console when you enter cordova build or run etc.

```
 ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
 ANDROID_HOME=C:\anypath (DEPRECATED)
```

Firstly, need to configure ANDROID_HOME path 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-environment-variables

In windows pc, you should enter path from environment variables settings.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5wqTSuL3j4 ( this video may help you )

2. Option-1 Then you can add new gradle version https://gradle.org/install/
3. Option-2 Replace gradle version on /platforms/android/app/build.gradle

   from  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.X`
   to    `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`

   You can find the right version of gradle by entering command editor:

   `gradlew --version` or `gradle --version`

   or checking this file in your project then find "distributionUrl"
   platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
   distributionUrl=\https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Hope it helps you.