# No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices

Tags: android, bintray

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

// load properties
Properties properties = new Properties()
File localPropertiesFile = project.file("local.properties");
if(localPropertiesFile.exists()){
    properties.load(localPropertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
}
File projectPropertiesFile = project.file("project.properties");
if(projectPropertiesFile.exists()){
    properties.load(projectPropertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
}

//read properties
def projectName = properties.getProperty("project.name")
def projectGroupId = properties.getProperty("project.groupId")
def projectArtifactId = properties.getProperty("project.artifactId")
def projectVersionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName
def projectPackaging = properties.getProperty("project.packaging")
def projectSiteUrl = properties.getProperty("project.siteUrl")
def projectGitUrl = properties.getProperty("project.gitUrl")

def developerId = properties.getProperty("developer.id")
def developerName = properties.getProperty("developer.name")
def developerEmail = properties.getProperty("developer.email")

def bintrayUser = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
def bintrayApikey = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

def javadocName = properties.getProperty("javadoc.name")

group = projectGroupId

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom {
            project {
                name projectName
                groupId projectGroupId
                artifactId projectArtifactId
                version projectVersionName
                packaging projectPackaging
                url projectSiteUrl
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id developerId
                        name developerName
                        email developerEmail
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection projectGitUrl
                    developerConnection projectGitUrl
                    url projectSiteUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

javadoc {
    failOnError false

    options{
        encoding 'UTF-8'
        charSet 'UTF-8'
        author true
        version projectVersionName
        links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api"
        title javadocName
    }
}

bintray {
    user = bintrayUser
    key = bintrayApikey
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        name = projectName
        websiteUrl = projectSiteUrl
        vcsUrl = projectGitUrl
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
    }
}
```

use this to upload the code to bintray will lead the error:
`No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices.`
if i use gradle 2.10 will run ok, but in the 2.14.1(AS 2.2 preview 7 need 2.14.1)will come this error!

Comment: I have the same issue, reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219692 (sadly didn't edit title well)

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Change maven gradle plugin version to 1.4.1 in project build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
}
```

Comment: is this version uploaded?

Comment: Guys does this dependencies and classpath chunk need to go inside a buildscript section of the build.gradle file?

Comment: Can someone explain how this fixes issue?

Comment: Giving Error : Could not find com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.4.1.

Comment: I freaking dont understand, but this worked and it pissed me off as well.

Answer (score 7):

Just add this line of code to your **project level gradle**

```
dependencies{
   classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We should not use any static version for maven gradle plugin. Check your distributionUrl from **gradle-wrapper.properties** file inside Android studio root folder.
Based on gradle version mentioned there you can find proper  **maven gradle plugin** version from [this link](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin)

just update that version that may solve your problem.