# No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices Error

Tags: android, maven-plugin

I have been trying to resolve this problem , have added dependencies (com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2) and (classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1') but was not able to resolve the Error.[Here is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ppiw.png).

Im new to android please help!

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38871519/3278589) is worked for me take a look and try.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependencies in `build.gradle` (project) file

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'}
```