# android studio: No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to start an  [this Android Studio app](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout).

when I open app with android studio I got this error:

```
No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices
```

I am new to android studio But I try solved this with seachring:

My android studio version is 2.2.3 and Android SDK tools: 25.2.5./tools version:25.0.2

I extract app and edit it for work my android studio version:

old **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'

}
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38871519/2726957) and changed it to this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
}
```

I also changed **gradle.properties** to this:

```
VERSION_NAME=1.2.0
VERSION_CODE=22
GROUP=com.daimajia.swipelayout

ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=16
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=25
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=25
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=25.0.2
```

Also change  **demo/build.gradle** to this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":library")
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.0.3@aar'
}
```

And finally change **library/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
}
apply from: './gradle-mvn-push.gradle'

apply plugin: 'android-maven'
// build a jar with source files
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}
artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

But I get that error again!

please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825451/no-service-of-type-factory-available-in-projectscopeservices)

Answer (score 3):

change dependency of project  build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
```

This is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Modify your build.gradle file

Here is an example:

[No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825451/no-service-of-type-factory-available-in-projectscopeservices/38871519#38871519)

You need to include the maven grade plugin, as shown in the link.

Answer (score 0):

choose the correct version of "android-maven-gradle-plugin", https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin

Comment: And what is the correct version then? And where does the OP set this version?

Answer (score 0):

Change or include below gradle plugin latest version to 1.4.1 in your main project build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
}
```

this is work for me...

Answer (score 0):

> No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices

You should use below in **`PROJECT`** level **`build.gradle`**

```
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
```

And include **`apply plugin`** tag in your **`APP`** Level **`build.gradle`**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```