# error in opening old project in new android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i had an android project in an old version of Android Studio. I re-installed my windows, and then i installed latest version of Android Studio.
Now, when i Open or Import my project i face this error:

```
No service of type Factory<LoggingManagerInternal> available in ProjectScopeServices.
Open File
```

and when i click on Open File link under the error, it directs me to

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

this is my project build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

version = '0.0.6'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/chunk-templates-3.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}

def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/kexanie/MathView'
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/kexanie/MathView.git'
group = 'io.github.kexanie.library'

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'

                // Add your description here
                name 'A library for displaying math formula in Android apps.'
                url siteUrl

                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'kexanie'
                        name 'Brian Lee'
                        email 'kexanie@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        name = "MathView"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
    }
}
```

and this is build.gradle app Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mathtools.user.com.mathtools"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "2.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':MathView')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.9.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

What do i do?

Comment: Possible duplication of [No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825451/no-service-of-type-factory-available-in-projectscopeservices)

Comment: I had seen this thread and had done it. This time i imported my project (instead of opening it), and did that, and problem solved. i'm not sure whether it was because of importing or not. Anyway, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change maven gradle plugin version to 1.4.1 in project build.gradle file

```
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
>     classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1' }
```

Comment: I had done this. But this time i imported my project (instead of opening it), and did that, and problem solved. i'm not sure whether it was because of importing or not. Anyway, thank you for your response.