# Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found in android

Tags: android, maven, camera, android-camera

I use the following library to add material design to my android project

https://github.com/boxme/SquareCamera

But after importing it as a module, I get the following error. How can I fix it

```
Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871084/how-to-fix-plugin-with-id-com-github-dcendents-android-maven-not-found-in-and

Comment: In your project build.gradle add this line in dependencies : `classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'`

Comment: @Ankur it's not working

Comment: can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: To long so can't post here....:)

Answer (score 0):

Update buildscript dependencies where your build.gradle file located in
Your_Project/build.gradle

***classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5' // This line you need to add

    }
}
```