# please explain me. 'Plugin with id not found', 'Android NDK undefined modules'

Tags: android, tess-two

I downloaded 'Tess-two' library. 
After project was ndk-builded&ant release in cmd, I import library in my project.

here was one error.

```
'Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.'
```

I had solved, just add 2 line in my app module gradle.
-like this

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
```

The error was completely solved, however another error appeared.

```
C:/android-ndk-r14/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:687: Android NDK: Module
 pngt depends on undefined modules: z
C:/android-ndk-r14/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:700: *** Android NDK: Ab
orting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies).Stop.
```

At this time, I just added one line in tess-two\jni\Application.mk.

```
APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true
```

Now, my project can build very well.
But I can't understand what I did.

Somebody please explain to me. What mean that error and how that codes could solve that error.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871084/how-to-fix-plugin-with-id-com-github-dcendents-android-maven-not-found-in-and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found. in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871084/how-to-fix-plugin-with-id-com-github-dcendents-android-maven-not-found-in-and)

Answer (score 1):

Module builds will now fail if they have any missing dependencies.
https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r14-beta1

Answer (score 1):

File > Project Structure
[image]

As I wrote above, since it is the specification of NDK r14, we could do it after downloading NDK r13b.

It will be r14 in the near future, but you can also download old revisions, so please check them yourself.