# Could not find android-maven-gradle-plugin.jar in Android Studio 3.1?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

My Android is work fine in Android Studio 3.0.1 , but it show the follow build error after I update to the Android Studio 3.1.

```
Could not find android-maven-gradle-plugin.jar (com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0).
```

Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/2.0/android-maven-gradle-plugin-2.0.jar

The **`build.gradle`** is like the following:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And in `app/build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aitrix.wen.seaglider"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':AHRSView')
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Did I missing something ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you apply the plugin `apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'`

Comment: @AmjadKhan I add it in the app/build.gradle. But it did not working.

Comment: are you sure android studio is not in offline mode ? else try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510176/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-head-received-status-code-5/49510333#49510333

Comment: Try to remove `apply plugin: 'android-maven'` and check or here you may find your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871084/how-to-fix-plugin-with-id-com-github-dcendents-android-maven-not-found-in-and

Comment: @SantanuSur I'm sure the android studio is not in offline mode.

Comment: if its not in offline mode ..try the above solution !!

Answer (score 1):

After I update the following , the project work fine.

Update

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

---

And Update

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
```

---

also update the `gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```