# Unable to build project after update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am not able to build my project getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException:
Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.
```

My `build.gradle` file is:

```groovy
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"

        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch

Comment: Try this thread once -https://stackoverflow.com/a/42645471/18362930

Comment: On the question itself, I'd say it's missing essential information.  You only supply the top level `build.gradle` where you specify its classpath.  The error indicates an error during `apply`, which does not appear above.  If the above link in the comment above does not resolve it, you could consider adding more context.