# Could not find com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Upon returning to my android project after a few years, I get the above error.

Here's my build file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        //classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath "com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here's some output:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
```

I'd have added all the output, but I'm limited to 30000 characters. Let me know if you need more output.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found. in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871084/how-to-fix-plugin-with-id-com-github-dcendents-android-maven-not-found-in-and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests the artifact couldn't be found in any of your declared repositories.

You can easily change that, however, by adding the `mavenCentral()` repository:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    ...
}
```